# stop loading a background 2 when i click on div autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete and when I click on it, it invites the behind down button on it although I do not click is a slight possibility of html or css to limit the clicks autocomplete? div looks like this

```
<div data-value="Alabama" style="padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 12px;">
     <b></b>A<b></b>l<b></b>a<b></b>b<b></b>a<b></b>m<b></b>a<b></b>
</div>
```

and the image link redirect to background of autocomplete look like this:

```
 <a href="http://example.com/example/">
  <img width="48%" height="150" class="alignnone wp-image-12 size-thumbnail" style="max-width: 150px; padding: 12px; width: 120px; height: 120px;" alt="kerkesa speciale" src="http://example.com/uu.png">
</a>
```

Comment: It is not clear in English what you are asking. Please indicate if the question relates to a Word Press plugin, and if so, which one.

Comment: sory my english is not so goodi have a autocomplete  and the autocomplete get show over 1 image with url  and when i click in 1 chois of autocomplete  open  it but automaticly clicked the back image with url 2

Comment: i am using this autocomplete http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete

Comment: Sounds like your click is bubbling up, but without more code and javascript. Impossible to tell

Comment: in this link ar all the javascripts what i am using for the autocomplete  http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete

Comment: but thets hapen just on mobile visiturs not in desktop pc